# I declared a variable in C. How come compiler allotted a memory space for variable?

Tags: c, variables, declaration, definition

As a beginner I have learned that only variable definition is allotted a memory in C. But for the following program the output is 0x7ffd12792034

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main(char args[], int vargs)
{
  int max;
  printf("%p\n", &max);
}
```

Comment: `int max;` is a variable definition.

Comment: @user2357112 what would be the function declaration then? I thought a declaration is something which only provides the name and type and not the value, and definition is declaration + value. Am I wrong ?

Comment: `int main(char args[], int vargs)` --> `int main(int argc, char *args[])` or `int main(void)`

Comment: A variable definition does not need to provide an initial value.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to understand the distinction between `declarations` and `definitions`.  But the line you have there is definitely a definition, so it does allocate space.  As a rough rule of thumb, it's a declaration if it includes the `extern` keyword, otherwise it's a definition.  (This rule isn't perfect, but it's a start.)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks a lot

Comment: @user2357112 Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [local variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable) is likely to sit on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (but sometimes the compiler would [optimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) to put it only in some [processor register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) or even forget it entirely). Your `int max;` is a local variable definition. Its initial value is indeterminate, which practically means that it holds whatever was in the memory location (or the register) before.

Your program is printing the address of that local variable, which is on the call stack.

Because of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) the actual value of that address might change (or not) from one program execution to the next. It is implementation specific.

BTW, you should enable all warnings and debug information when you compile. If you use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), you should compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. You would then have some warnings at least, in particular because your `main` function has the wrong signature. It should be `int main(int argc, char**argv)` and the runtime environment guarantee that `argc` is at least 1 and that the `argv` array is `NULL` terminated, with `argc` arguments which are non-`NULL` [unaliased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing) strings.

Beware of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Oh, so you mean in a function a local variable is always defined?

Comment: No, variable whose address is taken could sit in some register. They are likely to have a slot in the call stack.

Answer (score 1):

You've actually **defined** a variable in this case, not declared one.

If you had used the `extern` keyword, you would have a declaration.  But because you didn't, you have a definition.

An initializer such as `int max = 1;` is not necessary to have a definition.  The value will be unspecified until it is assigned one later, but it's still a definition.

If you declared the variable at file scope without an initializer, you would have a **tentative definition**.  You could then have a full definition with an initializer later, but it would have to match the type of the tentative definition.

Comment: But I read that all the functions and variables  in C have extern prepended to them by default?

Comment: @smartnerd Not sure what you read, but I think you may have misinterpreted it.

Comment: @smartnerd A function declaration is `extern` by default.  Those are easy to distinguish because they end with a `;` while a function definition has a body.  For a variable you should specify `extern` for a declaration.

Comment: Function definitions also have external linkage by default

Comment: @SteveSummit Here. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-extern-keyword-in-c/ Third para...last third line.

Comment: @smartnerd Okay, thanks. I'd say that's not the clearest explanation of the situation. For your question here, it comes closest to the truth when it says "we put extern explicitly for C variables when we want to declare them without defining them".  For a completely different treatment (still not as clear as I'd like), see https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx4b.html.

Comment: @SteveSummit Thanks. I will go through it.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing an address in your memory which is occupied for `int max` and ready to get initialize. By typing `int max` you already have the place where the variable will be stored if you give it a value.